# Wrong Image Format for bootm command ERROR: can't get kernel image!

Tags: u-boot

I keep getting this error when booting linux on ARM cortex A9 based xilinx chip:

```
U-Boot 2013.07 (Mar 31 2014 - 16:34:50)

Memory: ECC disabled
DRAM:  1 GiB
MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0
SF: Detected N25Q128A with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   Gem.e000b000
U-BOOT for Xilinx-ZC702-2013.3

Gem.e000b000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
BOOTP broadcast 3
BOOTP broadcast 4
BOOTP broadcast 5

Retry count exceeded
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
SF: Detected N25Q128A with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
SF: 11010048 bytes @ 0x520000 Read: OK
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
U-Boot-PetaLinux>
```

Even explicitly giving the command did not work:

```
U-Boot-PetaLinux> run sfboot
SF: Detected N25Q128A with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
SF: 11010048 bytes @ 0x520000 Read: OK
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
U-Boot-PetaLinux>
```

And my env variable:

```
U-Boot-PetaLinux> printenv bootcmd
bootcmd=setenv var "if test ${dtbsize} -le 0; then run sfboot; else run dtbboot; fi"; run var; setenv var
```

I am using uImage,which I got after converting zImage using mkimage tool.

Any idea what is wrong with the Image format?